# Python - removing a proportion/percentage of dictionary pairs

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nodes, percentage

I'm attempting to build a tool which can highlight social network nodes with the highest betweenness centrality. I compute this measure for all network nodes into a dictionary, sort this dictionary in order, and then keep only the top 3 pairs.

I want this tool to be scalable, so instead of top 3 pairs, I want to keep say the top 10% of pairs. I'm a newbie at Python, and have been unable to find how to do this. Please find my code below, with the number of nodes to remove specified by [:3]).

```
G = nx.Graph('data')
betweenness = dict(nx.betweenness_centrality(G))
import operator
betweenness_dict = dict(sorted(betweenness.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:3])
```

In essence, I want the [:3] to become [:10%]. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The formula for percentages is `p = part/whole * 100` - this is a very good starting point :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just calculate 10% of the length of your dictionary. Then feed this into your list slicing syntax. Given a dictionary `d`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

n = int(len(d) * 0.10)  # floor float result, as you must use an integer
res = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:n])
```

Comment: Thankyou, very quick reply and the code works perfectly.

Comment: @LaurieBamber Then select it as the correct answer :)